# The Phrase 'Take a Listen'

Tags: phrases, cliche

I've noticed the phrase 'take a listen' is used frequently on television by news anchors before playing news clips. Would you consider this usage too colloquial, and possibly a lazy use of language?

Comment: What qualifies as an unfortunate cliché, and how does it differ from something rendered acceptable through usage? It seems to me as if for something to be "cliché", as you put it, it would have to be used often.

Comment: As Tonepoet mentioned, the way this question is worded seems to invite answers based on personal opinion, rather than facts. Can you edit it to make it focus more on relatively objective information about this expression?

Comment: My guess is its frequency increases with the ease of extracting and cueing up clips; the anchor's intro cues the production people to play the clip and the audience to listen.  Also consider options.  Hear this! Here we go!  Now! Here's the clip!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't explained what you think might be wrong with this phrase.

Comment: Isn't usage and convention of words and phrases an aggregation of personal opinion? There's little objective 'truth' in language, which is a fluid thing, based on usage and trends. A respectful response to some of the above comments. David Foster Wallace wrote an interesting article on this. Having said this, I'll adjust the question.

Comment: I would place "take a listen" in the same basket of colloquials as "take a gander" and "take a look-see."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is acceptable English. It's not so much a cliché as an idiomatic phrase.

"Take" is an example of a "light verb". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_verb) gives more examples.