# Listen or listening?

Tags: differences

Which one of these two phrases is correct:

1. Enjoying my first listen of the new album.
2. Enjoying my first listening of the new album.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. What does your research tell you? Which do you think is correct, and why? As stated in our Help Center (https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this Proofreading question may be out of scope and better suited for our sister site, ELL.

Comment: If you try a Google search for each phrase (in double inverted commas to an ensure exact match) in turn, you will see that there are no hits. The two phrases are unacceptable. "Enjoying my first listen [to the new album]" **does** occur, but is probably best reserved for informal registers. "I'm listening to the new album for the first time, and really enjoying it" is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Both might look questionable at first blush, but it turns out that #1 seems to be gramatically correct.

"Listen" is used fairly often as a noun, as another post on this site noted ([The Phrase 'Take a Listen'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391351/the-phrase-take-a-listen)). As commentators on that post noted, whether or not that usage is too colloquial seems to be a matter of opinion. Apparently, however, "listen" has been used as a noun for a couple of centuries. At least one dictionary documents this usage in 1788 (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/listen#h2).

"Listening", as a gerund, functions by definition as a noun. This site offers many examples of how it could be used in a sentence: https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/listening.html None of those, however, accompanies the word with one or more adjectives, as #2 does. It doesn't sound quite right in #2, and this may be due to the use of "my first" before it. There are, of course, plenty of adjectives that can be idiomatically used with "listening" (ex: "active", "careful", "respectful", etc. http://adjective1.com/for-listening/), but the combination offered in #2 does not sound as though it should be among them.

Comment: Yeap...I hear it everyday on CNN: "Take a listen."